# What word does this photo of a mouse represent?

Tags: rebus

What word does this photo of a mouse represent?

[image]

Image source: adapted from [Wikimedia commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Mus#/media/File:Mouse-19-Dec-2004.jpg).

Comment: Is it too snarky to say "a mouse"?

Comment: This makes me think of computer mouse resolution (AKA DPI).

Comment: Why did you change the picture??

Comment: Because I didn't have copyrights and some users were uncomfortable with that.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

My answer is

> Anony-mouse

or simply

> Anonymous

since

> pixelating the face is done to make the identity of the person (or animal) anonymous.

Answer (score 34):

My answer is

> Mouse-aic (as in Mosaic, which refers to the pixelated blur, described on [this page](http://www.sitepoint.com/censor-your-images-with-a-mosaic-in-photoshop/))

Comment: Oh wow that's genius. I hadn't though of it that way

Comment: In this case, however, the whole mouse would have to be pixelated.

Answer (score 3):

I thought of:

> Mouse-touch (moustache), since the original *mouse* picture has been *touch*ed (and the mouse in the picture obviously has one).